# How to read environment variables from .env file rather than store in paw config

Tags: paw-app

Is there a way to have a Paw environment import configuration from a local file such as .env rather than save them in the Paw configuration itself? I'd like to check my Paw config into version control but do not want to leak auth tokens.

Answer (score 2):

We planning on having local environment variables that will only be accessible to you. For now you can either set a File dynamic value in the environment variable to read from your local file and combine it with the regex (https://paw.cloud/docs/advanced/file-dynamic-value-anywhere) or you can also use Secure dynamic values for sensitive data and it will be locally encrypted (https://paw.cloud/docs/security/obfuscate-and-encrypt)